# Programmatically set layout_toLeftOf and layout_below for TextView

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm creating an arbitrary number of TextViews contained within a RelativeLayout. How do I place the TextViews below or next to each other programmatically?

I'm guessing I should use *layout_toLeftOf* and *layout_below*, but how?

I know I can use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, but that only seems to position the layout and not the individual TextViews.

Attempt so far:

```
public void updateTS ( ArrayList<String> arrayList ) {
    RelativeLayout rl = ( RelativeLayout ) mView.findViewById ( R.id.overview );
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );

    for ( int i = 0; i < arrayList.size (); i++ ) {
        TextView tv = new TextView ( getActivity () );
        tv.setId ( i );
        tv.setText ( arrayList.get ( i ).toString () );

        if ( i > 0 ) {
            lp.addRule ( RelativeLayout.BELOW, i - 1 );
        }

        rl.addView ( tv );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set a new `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` on the `TextView`, not the `RelativeLayout`:

```
public void updateTS ( ArrayList<String> arrayList ) {
    RelativeLayout rl = ( RelativeLayout ) mView.findViewById ( R.id.overview );

    for ( int i = 0; i < arrayList.size (); i++ ) {
        TextView tv = new TextView ( getActivity () );
        tv.setId ( i );
        tv.setText ( arrayList.get ( i ).toString () );

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ( RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );

        if ( i > 0 ) {
            lp.addRule ( RelativeLayout.BELOW, i - 1 );
        }

        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
        rl.addView ( tv );
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, not following. Mind elaborating?

Comment: Thanks! Wow, the documentation is *not* easy to follow.